# A question refresh freezes the entire app

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, android-app

I'm using Android App version 1.0.23 on a HTC Velocity 4G running Android 4.0.3. I've experienced the same issue on previous versions of the Android App on a HTC One running Android 4.3 (rather than 4.0.3).

Whenever I have a question open on the question tab, and I pull down to refresh that tab, the entire app is frozen for the full duration of the refresh. *Nowhere else in the app* freezes like this: the answers tab, the questions list, and notes all refresh without a freeze.

I don't have a screenshot, as it would just be a snapshot of the point in the refresh process at which the app froze!

This is not a breaking bug, but it's inconvenient, in cases such as deciding I'd rather hit back to leave a question rather than wait for it to refresh (not possible, since the app's frozen).

Comment: Repro'd on Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2, app 1.0.23. It's like the process is done on UI thread, locking the UI and preventing any interaction with the view. (Note: this might not be the cause, only the effect is similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe we missed that. Reloading of a question was being done on the UI thread, but I hadn't seen it since I normally test on fast WiFi. As of version 1.0.24 this will be fixed, thanks!

Comment: Try testing on a slow connection too! Maybe one with a simulated delay. I've had a couple of bugs show up as a result of low speed or spots where my mobile network blacks out.

Comment: ^I noticed the same thing happening to me, if the 3g is spotty.